# Update sqlite db entry using put method flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I want to update sqlite entry using put http method. When I send request via postman I get this error:

## Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/api/users/<int:user_id>', methods=['PUT'])
def put_user(user_id):
    user = {
        'id': user_id,
        'login': request.json['login'],
        'password': request.json['password'],
    }
    cursor.execute('UPDATE USERS SET login=?, password=? WHERE id=?', (user['login'], user['password'], user['id']))
    connection.commit()
    return jsonify(user), 200
```

Here is request:

http://192.168.0.101:5000/api/users/4/

```
{   
    "id": 4,
    "login": "bbbb",
    "password": "aaaa"
}
```

http://192.168.0.101:5000/api/users/

```
[
     {
         "id": 1,
         "login": "123",
         "password": "1231231"
     },
     {
         "id": 2,
         "login": "login",
         "password": "sfsdfsd"
     },
     {
         "id": 3,
         "login": "4444",
         "password": "sass"
     },
     {
         "id": 4,
         "login": "ffff",
         "password": "aaaa"
     }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: I added key **'Accept'** and value **'application/json'** to headers tab in postman and it works!